# Dynamically added content on template don't respond to Javascript/AJAX/Jquery in CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

This is my sample code for the template.

```
<?php
 defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
  ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>WebLAB</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/css/bootstrap.css" />
 </head>
 <body class="container">   
 <header class="panel-heading" role="navigation">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>">WebLAB</a>
  <nav>
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
      <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>portal/registration">Register</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>portal/about">About this site</a></li>
      </ul>
  </nav>
 </header>
 <section class="container">

  <!--- Dynamic content is loaded here!-->
 <?php if(isset($content)) echo $content; ?>


 </section> 
 <footer class="panel-footer text-center">
  <span><small>All Rights Reserved | &copy; <?php echo date('Y'); ?> Christ the King College-ICT Team</small></span>
 </footer>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/js/jQuery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

This code below is the content I am LOADING to the code above (It's embedding the content dynamically). My problem is that the Javascript code I am trying to apply to an element doesn't respond. I have tried also adding the script on the main page above.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#jq').click(function(){
                  alert("Hi");
                });
            });
    </script>

    <section class="col-md-8">
      <p>
         <h2 id="jq">Register Your Account here to Login!</h2>
      <p>
      <article>
        <p>
          You can only access your account when the admin 
          approves your request for registration.
        </p>
      </article>
    </section>

  <section class="col-md-4">   
    <form method="post" class="regform" action="<?php echo base_url();?>portal/register" role="form">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Username" id="sample">Username:</label>
         <input type="Username" class="form-control" id="Username" name="username" placeholder="example@mail.com" required>

      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
         <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" name="password" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="pwd">Retype-Password:</label>
         <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" name="repassword" required>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Register</button>
   </form>
</section>
```

I am using this technique in CodeIgniter 3 controller.

```
public function registration() {
    $data = null;
    $data['content'] = $this->load->view('pages/registration', $data, true);

    $this->load->view('template/temp_portal.php', $data);
}
```

Sorry for the messy code. Your help is much appreciated. This is just a sample code BTW.

Comment: same question everwhere , `$(document).ready(function(){
                $(document').on('click','#jq',function(){
                  alert("Hi");
                });
            });`

Comment: thanks for this info. Convert2Int. should I add this script to the template or to the content?

Comment: should this code only available in the page where button defined

Comment: yes, I think that the script should come in together where the button is define when it is embedded or loaded to main page or template. Do you have any recommendation on what should I do?

Comment: seperate js code from html and make them loaded when page loads first time not with partial

Comment: What error can be seen when inpecting console?

Comment: Can you post some example code?

Comment: @Tpojka I haven't seen any error. It's just that the JS code is not working, when I trigger it's event.

Comment: I find my problem very funny. Thanks for the response though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is you are using jquery before loading the library. load your JS file including jquery library in your `head` tag. It will work i.e

```
<?php
 defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
 ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>WebLAB</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/js/jQuery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body class="container">   
 <header class="panel-heading" role="navigation">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>">WebLAB</a>
  <nav>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>portal/registration">Register</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>portal/about">About this site</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
</header>
<section class="container">

 <!--- Dynamic content is loaded here!-->
 <?php if(isset($content)) echo $content; ?>


</section> 
<footer class="panel-footer text-center">
 <span><small>All Rights Reserved | &copy; <?php echo date('Y'); ?> Christ the King College-ICT Team</small></span>
</footer>


</body>
</html>
```

Try this and check your console what error showing now

**Double check your jQuery library link is ok or not**

Comment: I have tried adding it, but it still doesn't work. I have tried moving it from the content to the template. I don't know if I did it correctly. I hope you can give me some sample or links, I'd appreciate it. So that I can learn from it too. Thanks btw :)

Comment: i think live event  has been removed use on event instead

Comment: @ConvertToInt32 right you are. But after adding migrate library it works

Comment: Is it a concern where you put the js script? I have tried putting the script to the head BTW, but it seems to never work. I don't see why placing it top or bottom is an issue, because I have called the script at the template and my custom js is placed on the page i am trying to dynamically load.

Comment: BTW your content is not dynamic in context of jquery. your any jquery code will never work if you load jquery library after your jquery code, as you done. Check my edit again

Comment: Yes, I am not using javascript to dynamically load a page. I am utilizing the capability of CodeIgniter to load a page on the controller.

Comment: BTW, I am loading the page on the template like this                                                                                                           $data = NULL;
$data['content'] = $this->load->view('pages/registration', $data, TRUE);
$this->load->view('template/temp_portal.php',$data);

Comment: replace your template code with my latest edited code and follow the instruction

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87086/discussion-between-rejoanul-alam-and-jomar-llevado).